# Is it possible to have 2 physical partitions instead of the default 10 in Azure Cosmos DB?

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

Is it possible to have 2 physical partitions instead of the default 10 in Azure Cosmos DB?

We switched to a partitioned collection to have better performance on aggregate queries. However since we have 2.500 RU/s for the entire collection, this leaves us with 250 RU/s per physical partition (Cosmos DB automatically creates 10 physical partition).

We would like to improve the RU/s per partition, without scaling the RU/s for the whole collection. So having fewer partitions would benefit us.

**-Edit-**

The azure support changed the default collection size to 20gb with 2 physical partitions for us. In this way we have higher performance per physical partition. Since performance is set on collection level and divided by the amount of physical partitions.

The support also said that it was not possible to alter partition size, so a physical partition in azure kosmos db is fixed to 10gb. When you need more storage there is no other way than setting a higher RU/s for your collection to maintain the same level of performance per partition.

Comment: I'm not aware of a way to control the number of physical partitions at this time. However, I'd be curious to know more about the specific query patterns you're trying to optimize. There may be a simpler solution

Comment: @JesseCarter We have the following query: https://pastebin.com/9QdZ1Emd. Which would result in this error: "Cross partition query only supports 'VALUE <AggreateFunc>' for aggregates.". Even though we use VALUE, we needed a partitioned collection in order for the query to work.

Comment: Have you tested to see if you still get the error when running in a cross partition collection? I don't think that switching to multi-partition is a work around for supporting this query. You should get the same error

Comment: The same query works like a charm now.

Comment: Interesting... I'll have to revisit how the aggregate functionality differs between single/multi collections

Comment: @JesseCarter Ofcourse we had to provide a partition key in order for the query to work. But in our first Cosmos DB collection there were no partitions. So we could not provide a partition key, and as a result we could not get the query to work.

Comment: @SenkZ - When you are providing more details to a question, please *edit your question* to include those details. Don't send people to an external site to see your query.

Comment: @DavidMakogon, thanks for the advice. However in this case I suppose that the query is irrelevant for the question being asked.. I try to be as specific as possible in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it possible to have 2 physical partitions instead of the default 10 in Azure Cosmos DB?

The number of partitions is determined by Cosmos DB based on the storage size and the provisioned throughput of the container (collections (for document), graphs, or tables), and Partition management is fully managed by Azure Cosmos DB. After a collection is created, only ***THROUGHPUT (RU/s)*** is enabled to be modified via Azure portal. As Jesse Carter said, currently it seems no a direct way to control the number of physical partitions.

For detailed information about partitioning in Azure Cosmos DB, please check [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/partition-data#partitioning-in-azure-cosmos-db).

Comment: You confirm my suspicion that it isn't possible to manually configure physical partitions. However, my question is not limited to manual configurations possibilities.

Is it possible to have fewer partitions at all? And at different sizes than 10gb per partition? (even if this has to be done via azure support). I can't find any documentation on this.

Comment: ``Is it possible to have fewer partitions at all? And at different sizes than 10gb per partition?`` We deal with **logical partitions** when we create partitioned collection. I do not find any documentations that explain strategies for your requirements, you can try to contact cosmosdb team on askdocdb@microsoft.com, perhaps they can help you achieve your requirements.

Comment: The azure support changed the default collection size to 20gb with 2 physical partitions for us. In this way we have higher performance per physical partition. Thanks helping looking for an answer.